# Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 Windows 10 Projects Designer's Load Failed

Tags: load, designer, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, ctp

I am trying to develop Windows 10 Project with VS2015 CTP6 on Windows 10 Technical Preview. I can't use designer because of this error. How can I solve this?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I also had this in 10041 and gave it up. I'll wait for a new CTP + new Tools

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have last build of Windows 10. I had the same problem with build 9xxxx and solved the issue by installing build 10041. Also [Here](http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/deployment-of-windows-10-app-failed-with-error-0x80073CFD) explains that problem can be solved by updating windows (without installing a new build).

Error message is: Deployment Register opteration with target failed with error (0x80073CFD) [ERROR_INSTALL_PREREQUISITE_FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to the latest Windows 10 build in the Fast ring, build 10049. It seems to break some things for the developers.

*There are 2 issues using Visual Studio 2015 preview on this build:The emulators will not boot and you won’t be able to deploy a Windows Universal app to the Mobile emulator. **The XAML designer in VS and Blend will crash when opened.***

*If you are a developer using these
   tools today to develop Windows Universal apps and need this
   functionality to work – we recommend switching to the Slow ring until
   we release a patch to fix these issues.*

Source: http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/03/30/windows-10-technical-preview-build-10049-now-available/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today also.  The solution is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn706236.aspx

Short answer: enabling developer mode has changed, but the new route is currently broken and requires manually enabling 2 group policies using gpedit.msc.  The designer needs these policies in order to activate itself.

Under **"Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Package Deployment"**, enable:

- **Allow all trusted apps to install** (Enables your device for sideloading apps)
- **Allow development of Windows Store applications and installing them directly from an IDE** (Enables your device for development from Visual Studio)

Then reboot.